# Rep calculation quandaries

Tags: discussion, reputation

Sorry if this is a duplicate but searched and couldn't find a clear answer for this one. On StackOverflow you get +100 rep once you hit +200 rep, right? So how is it some users have rep counts of 2XX, i.e. "218" or "267" ? Once I hit 200 rep it automatically jumped to 300-something. If people have rep in 2XX value is this a result of downvotes?

Similarly, I've noticed that a person can have "101" rep on a question that's received 20 upvotes, i.e. [How to make a curved onscreen keyboard for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13984378/how-to-make-a-curved-onscreen-keyboard-for-android). Did this person just receive a lot of downvotes?

This doesn't make sense, what am I missing?

Comment: You need at least one other account on the network to get the +100 bonus.

Comment: I know, that wasn't what I was asking but thanks.

Comment: That's what I'm saying. If you don't have another account on the network, you won't get that +100. So that's how you can end up in the 2XX without resorting to downvotes or bounties.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. That answers the first case. What about the second? How can a person have a question with 20 upvotes and yet only have 101 rep, or even less? Do they just get a ton of downvotes?

Comment: Question upvotes only give +5. `20 * 5 = 100`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So how is it some users have rep counts of 2XX, i.e. "218" or "267" ?

The +100 association bonus only comes when you have at least one other account on the network.

So having no other accounts is how it's possible to get rep in the 200-300 range without resorting to downvotes, bounties, or deletions.

> Similarly, I've noticed that a person can have "101" rep on a question
>   that's received 20 upvotes,

Question upvotes are only +5. So 20 upvotes * 5 = 100. Nothing unusual here.